# How to remove image from Joomla cache

Tags: cache

I have to make changes to an image on an old Joomla site (V 3.7.4). Logging into the backend causes a server error 500.

I've updated the image (which is located in templates/shaper_helix_ii/images), however the old version of the image is still showing on the site.

I've deleted all files in all subfolders of cache/.

Is there somewhere in the file system where Joomla caches images?

I've cleared the page cache, but [apparently](https://docs.joomla.org/Cache) there is a module cache, however I haven't been able to find it in the file system.

Any pointers as to where images are cached would be much appreciated.

PS: I've been using an incognito tab in Chrome, so the page definitely isn't cached locally.

Comment: I managed to turn off the cache with the following line in configuration.php...
`public $caching = '0';  /* was '1' */`
... this isn't exactly what I was after (ideally the site would stay cached) but it has achieved the purpose of making the new version of the image visible.

Answer (score 1):

Cache clearing instructions can be found in the Joomla! docs here:

https://docs.joomla.org/Help39:Site_Maintenance_Clear_Cache

Here are some additional resources:

- https://www.templatemonster.com/help/joomla-3-x-clear-cache.html
- https://www.joomlabamboo.com/blog/how-to-joomla/how-to-clear-cache-in-joomla3
- https://www.cloudaccess.net/joomla-knowledgebase/108-joomla-3-1/maintenance/578-clearing-cache-in-joomla-3-0.html

All of the above links provide tutorials with screenshots and explanations so they should put you on the right path.

There's even an extension from Regular Labs:

https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/cachecleaner

Comment: Thanks for all those resources @mickmackusa, however I've already looked at many of them. I need to be able to clear the cache without logging into Joomla (since logging in causes an error). So just using the file manager.

Answer (score 0):

Helix_v2 doesn't have extra caching functionality. You just clean your Joomla default cache from the site Administrator area & check caching settings from the global configuration system tab.

Comment: Hi @Toufic, thanks for that. However, as stated in my question, I need to be able to clear the cache without going into the Joomla backend. It's an old site, and the backend keeps crashing when I try to log in.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the Helix issue. This issue occurred for the Joomla. You should make the update the Joomla core files again. Thanks

Comment: I see no reason for you to post a second answer. To improve your initial post, you may [edit](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/posts/26349/edit) it. Your answer has been flagged as low value due to its length and content.  You might explain more precisely why you believe upgrading will fix the problem.